# Improved stack implementation using a linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, stack

This is a followup to

- [Simple stack implementation using linked list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69402/simple-stack-implementation-using-linked-list)

Since my original stack implementation has lots of bugs that I did not notice, I thought I would recreate and try to improve it. Please review this version.

Note about pointers: I know using `std::unique_ptr` is better so we don't need to do manual deletes, but when I tried it here it results in disaster. I think I don't yet know how to really use it. So I did not use it in this code.

```
template<class T>
struct Node {
    T item;
    Node* next;
    Node(const T& t, Node* link) :item{t}, next{link} { }
};

template<class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack() : first{nullptr}, n{0} {}
    int size() const { return n; }
    bool empty() const { return n == 0; }
    Stack(const Stack&);
    Stack(Stack&&);
    Stack& operator=(const Stack&);
    Stack& operator=(Stack&&);
    void push(const T&);
    void pop();
    T peek() const;
    ~Stack() {
        while (!empty()) {
            pop();
        }
    }
private:
    Node<T>* first;
    std::size_t n;
};

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack& s) :first{nullptr}, n{0}{
    for (auto t = s.first; t != nullptr; t = t->next) {
        push(t->item);
    }
}

template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack& s) {
    for (auto t = s.first; t != nullptr; t = t->next) {
        push(t->item);
    }
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack&& s) :first{s.first}, n{s.n} {
    s.first = nullptr;
    s.n = 0;
}

template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack&& s) {
    first = s.first;
    n = s.n;
    s.first = nullptr;
    s.n = 0;
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& t) {
    first = new Node<T>{t,first};
    ++n;
}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    Node<T>* oldfirst = first;
    first = first->next;
    delete oldfirst;
    --n;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::peek() const {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    return first->item;
}
```

How can I make this code better, particularly copy and move?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't repeat code:

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack& s) {
    for (auto t = s.first; t != nullptr; t = t->next) {
        push(t->item);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This is not really an assignment but an append. I think most people would not expect that. You should probably release the original list before copying over the source into this object.

An easier way to implement the assignment operator is to use the copy and swap idiom.

```
// Notice the pass by value creates an implicit copy.
// You then just swap the content of the current object
// with the parameter s.
// When the parameter goes out of scope it deletes the old
// data stack.
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack s) {
    std::swap(first,   s.first);
    std::swap(n,       s.n);
    return *this;
}
```

You move assignment leaks:

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack&& s) {
    first = s.first;
    n = s.n;
    s.first = nullptr;
    s.n = 0;
    return *this;
}
```

The current value of `first` is leaked. The best way to do this is to swap the content of this object with the incomming object.

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack&& s) {
    std::swap(first,   s.first);
    std::swap(n,       s.n);
    return *this;
}
```

Let the other object do the clean up when it goes out of scope.

You implemented a push by copy:

```
void push(const T&);
```

Why not have a push by move:

```
void push(T&&);
```

I would make the `Node` structure a private implementation detail of stack. That way other people can not rely on that detail when they use your code.

```
template<class T>
class Stack {
     struct Node {....} 
};
```

Your peak creates a copy of the object.

```
   T Stack<T>::peek() const {
// ^ Return by value creates a copy.
```

I would return by reference. I would also rovide two version. One to return by const reference (for const version of the stack), and a normal return by reference so you can look at the top value and potentially alter it without removing it from the stack:

```
T const& Stack<T>::peek() const { ....
T&       Stack<T>::peek()       { ....
```

Your destructor checks `empty()` then calls `pop()` which checks `empty()`. This is a bit redundant. You could have a private version of pop that does not check empty.

```
~Stack() {
    while (!empty()) {
        noneCheckedPop();
    }

void Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    noneCheckedPop();
}

private:
void Stack<T>::noneCheckedPop() {
    Node<T>* oldfirst = first;
    first = first->next;
    delete oldfirst;
    --n;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the title of my question the improve part( might not be fitting after all and might mislead viewers. Should I edit it?

Comment: @recursivePointer: No. It is an improvement. Next time use `Superior Improved` :-)

Comment: tiny comment: I almost always prefer `nullptr_t` to `nullptr`, especially when writing templates .

Comment: @user2485710: Can you expand on that. I am not sure I understand what you are referring too with that statement.

Comment: Hi @Loki, I just noticed you passed a const argument in your copy assignment. Why is that? I thought you will change the values if you are going to swap objects. So I think it should not be const. I tested this and I got an error.

Comment: @morbidCode: It is a bug. I have fixed.

Answer (score 6):

First observation: your copy constructor and copy assignment create a stack with the items in the reverse order!.

I would use `unique_ptr` to manage `Node` lifetimes, one caveat here is performance may be slightly suboptimal on `Stack` destruction due to the recursive destructor calls. I'd also make `Node` a private nested struct in `Stack` since it's an implementation detail. Since `t` is a sink parameter to the Node constructor you could take it by value and `std::move` it into place but since you're the only one using the Node constructor you can save a possible extra move by making the parameter `T&& t`.

If you use `unique_ptr` to manage Node lifetimes and C++11 member initialization for `n` you can make your default constructor `= default`.

`Stack::size()` should return the same type as your `n` member, `size_t`, rather than int. With C++14 you can just use auto return type deduction to avoid the risk of this mistake.

`Stack::push()` should take its argument by value for the same reason as the Node construtor, it's a sink argument. In this case you could avoid a possible extra move by providing both `push(const T&)` and `push(T&&)` overloads but taking by value is simpler.

I'd call `Stack::peek()` `Stack::top()` for consistency with `std::stack`. It should also return a reference rather than by value. This is both for efficiency (no copies of the item) and also avoids the possibility of `top()` throwing an exception (`T`'s copy constructor might throw an exception in general).

If you use `unique_ptr` to manage `Node` lifetimes you don't need an explicit destructor, the default destructor will be correct. The default move constructor and move assignment can also be used, although you must explicitly request them. Copy assignment can be implemented using 'copy and swap'.

I wouldn't throw exceptions on a `pop()` or `top()` on an empty stack. I think it's more idiomatic C++ for this to be undefined (as it is for `std::stack`) but I can see a case for your choice.

Here's how I might implement it:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
    struct Node {
        T item;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
        Node(T&& t, std::unique_ptr<Node>&& tail) : item{std::move(t)}, next{std::move(tail)} {}
    };

public:
    Stack() = default;
    Stack(const Stack&);
    Stack(Stack&& x) = default;
    Stack& operator=(const Stack& x) {
        Stack temp{x};
        std::swap(*this, temp);
        return *this;
    }
    Stack& operator=(Stack&&) = default;

    auto size() const noexcept { return n; }
    bool empty() const noexcept { return n == 0; }

    void push(T t) {
        head = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(t), std::move(head));
        ++n;
    }
    void pop() noexcept {
        head = std::move(head->next);
        --n;
    }

    T& top() noexcept { return head->item; }
    const T& top() const noexcept { return head->item; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
    std::size_t n{};
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack& s) {
    Stack<T> temp;
    auto it = s.head.get();
    while (it) {
        temp.push(it->item);
        it = it->next.get();
    }
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        push(std::move(temp.top()));
        temp.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make `Node<T>` an inner struct of `Stack`. That would be better to avoid having a `Node` type
visible in the global namespace which is not used elsewhere. If you make it a nested type, it
no longer needs to be a template, because it will inherit type `T` from `Stack`:

```
template<class T>
class Stack {
public:

    ....

private:

    struct Node {
        T item;
        Node* next;
        Node(const T& t, Node* link) :item{t}, next{link} { }
    };
};
```

---

Some spacing between the functions in the declaration wouldn't harm.
It would be nicer to give constructor and operators a little more visibility:

```
Stack() : first{nullptr}, n{0} {}
Stack(const Stack&);
Stack(Stack&&);

Stack& operator=(const Stack&);
Stack& operator=(Stack&&);

void push(const T&);
void pop();
T peek() const;

int size() const { return n; }
bool empty() const { return n == 0; }

~Stack() {
    while (!empty()) {
        pop();
    }
}
```

---

`Stack::size()` should return a `size_t`, which is an unsigned integral type. Not a signed `int`:

```
std::size_t size() const { return n; }
```

---

The assignment operator is appending to the current stack:

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(const Stack& s) {
    for (auto t = s.first; t != nullptr; t = t->next) {
        push(t->item);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Since you didn't clear `this` stack first, if it has any current data, that data will remain and
`s` will be appended to it. Was this the intention?

Also, the order of the elements will be reversed from the source stack in
both the copy constructor and assignment operator.

---

Your move assignment operator leaks memory!

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack&& s) {
    first = s.first;
    n = s.n;
    s.first = nullptr;
    s.n = 0;
    return *this;
}
```

Once again, if `this` stack is not empty, its contents are lost into the void
once you do this:

```
first = s.first;
n = s.n;
```

You need to first dispose the current stack before taking ownership of `s`.